# Stuck on a HttpPost method, trying to input JSON text, but object is supposedly "empty"

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to post data to a database, using postman, but i I either get a 500 internal server error, or my object is empty.

```
[HttpPost()]
   public IActionResult CreateCustomer([FromBody]CustomerForCreationDto customerInfo)
   {

        var customerError = "Please look at your data and make sure it's not empty, incorrect, or has values that are the same!";
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        // Convert CustomerForCreationDto to Customer entity
        customer.Adress = customerInfo.Adress;
        customer.Name = customerInfo.Name;
        customer.MobileNr = customerInfo.MobileNr;
        customer.CustomerId = customerInfo.CustomerId;
        customer.CreatedAtDate = new DateTime(2011,01,01,12,12,12);
        customer.UpdatedAtDate = customer.CreatedAtDate;

        _customerInfoRepository.AddCustomer(customer);


        if (customerInfo == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(customerError);
        }

        if (customerInfo.Name == customerInfo.Adress || customerInfo.Name == customerInfo.MobileNr || customerInfo.MobileNr == customerInfo.Adress)
        {
            return BadRequest(customerError);
        }


        return CreatedAtRoute("", new { customerId = customer.CustomerId }, customer);
   }
```

I am unsure what is wrong. My JSON i pass through in postman is this.

```
{
"customerId": 5,
"name": "Johnathan",
"adress": "12 Maritz Street, Maryland",
"mobileNr": "0723423789",
"createdAtDate": "2001-10-11T11:12:20",
"updatedAtDate": "2017-08-11T14:13:29"
```

}

CustomerForCreationDTO

```
public class CustomerForCreationDto
    {

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Adress { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string MobileNr { get; set; }


        public DateTime CreatedAtDate { get; set; }


        public DateTime UpdatedAtDate  { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: could u plz add your `CustomerForCreationDto`?

Comment: did you set `Content-Type` to `application/json`, plus do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: @MohammadAli I did set it to application/json, yes. And i don't think so, am unsure what stacktrace is

Comment: stacktrace is the exception details, when error code 500 shows this means that there is an exception being thrown in your code, without being catched, so the exception have a stacktrace

Comment: Why are your validation checks `customerInfo == null` at the end of the method? They should be at the beginning of the method

Comment: @HenkBlaauw, does your `customerInfo` have value for each of property that you sent from postman. add breakpoint in controller method and check

Comment: @AmanB, i realised this after i posted the question, and i did correct it. Thank you

Comment: @ershoaib i will do this and check it, will try newtonsoft as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `JsonProperty` for each of model's property to its respective name of json's key that comes from posted body.

Download `Newtonsoft.json` from Nuget Package Manager and add namespace to your model like
`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
public class CustomerForCreationDto
{
    [JsonProperty("customerId")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [JsonProperty("adress")]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [JsonProperty("mobileNr")]
    public string MobileNr { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdAtDate")]
    public DateTime CreatedAtDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updatedAtDate")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAtDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @ershoabib, this sadly did not help, still getting the "No route matches the supplied values" error

Comment: @HenkBlaauw, I think your customer has been added to db successfully now this line => `return CreatedAtRoute("", new { customerId = customer.CustomerId }, customer);` gives you problem bcoz it may does not find any route. check once again and let me know

Comment: i have come to the same conclusion after adding line breaks, and the program runs fine up until that line. Now i am stuck there, and no clue how to progress further with it

Comment: @HenkBlaauw, it means your customer added successfully? and where you have to redirect after adding customer?

Comment: @HenkBlaauw, try this line `return Ok(customer);`

Comment: i think so. But the redirect after adding is what im struggling with now. My experience with c#, and asp.net core is very little, hence my struggle. If i figure it out i will let you know. But thank you!

Comment: @HenkBlaauw, I think I resolved your problem that you mainly asked in your question,  and successfully added your customer to db.  If answer help you then mark tick on right side of answer to make it green.

Comment: it helped me yes, but the customer is not added to the db, but yes, your answer is correct. Thank you

Comment: wait, did u able to get `customerInfo` in your action method?